# Pandas reading data as NaT and nan

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to read in some sample data that is in a CSV file which contains the following. However when I print out the data in the dataframe many of the columns are null. I manually set the column datatypes because I thought that might be the issue, however that didn't solve the problem. Some help would be appreciated.

Data:

```
People_id,datetime,First Name,Last Name,Utilization,Chargeability,Target,Employee Type,Business Unit,Business Group
2222,2020-05-03,FirstName,LastName,0.8,0.9,0.4,Employee,GGGG,G1
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd



data = pd.read_csv (r'C:\Users\Name\Documents\testdata.csv')   
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['People_id', 'WeekEnding', 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'Utilization', 'Chargeability', 'Target', 'EmployeeType', 'BusinessUnit', 'BusinessGroup'])

df.dropna(subset=['People_id', 'Utilization', 'Chargeability', 'Target'])

df.FirstName = df.FirstName.astype(str)
df.LastName = df.LastName.astype(str)
df.EmployeeType = df.EmployeeType.astype(str)
df.BusinessUnit = df.BusinessUnit.astype(str)
df.BusinessGroup = df.BusinessGroup.astype(str)
df['WeekEnding'] = pd.to_datetime(df['WeekEnding'])

for row in df.itertuples():
    print (row.People_id)
    print (row.WeekEnding)
    print (row.FirstName)
    print (row.LastName)
    print (row.Utilization)
    print (row.Chargeability)
    print (row.Target)
    print (row.EmployeeType)
    print (row.BusinessUnit)
    print(row.BusinessGroup)
```

Output:

```
2222
NaT
nan
nan
0.8
0.9
0.4
nan
nan
nan
```

Comment: Solved. I just didn't use the `df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['People_id', 'WeekEnding', 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'Utilization', 'Chargeability', 'Target', 'EmployeeType', 'BusinessUnit', 'BusinessGroup'])` line and just used the `data` object throughout.

Comment: can you share few data records